# Bash script manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, function, text, find

I work with `Bash` script and I want to get line from  big text by special text

for example i have these lines

```
first fffffffffffffffffffffffffff
.................................
second ssssssssssssssssssssssssss
.................................
third ttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
```

and I want to get `ssssssssssssssssssssssssss` string .

Can anybody help me?

Comment: By what criterion do you select the output? Is it the second row second column? Is it anything after the first word in the second line? something else? please clarify

Comment: Describe what you want as a generic question like :"I want to extract the second string in the second column." Or "I want to extract second string after the string `second`"

Comment: Not second line .it is simple example

Comment: If you don't explain clearly, we're just guessing at the solution.

Comment: Can't you put the string in a file?  If not, then redirect it to the grep I show below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
echo "$longstring" | awk '$1 == "second" { print $2 }'
```

Comment: If not second line, then what is it?

Comment: My answer doesn't look for second line, it looks for line beginning with the word "second". If that's not the way to find the string you want, you need to improve the question.

Comment: i have no file, i have long string

Comment: @user2699859 well, remove the `filename` and send your stdout to the `awk` command, as in `... | awk '$1 == "second" { print $2 }'`, or use @Jim's answer, which is equivalent.

Comment: Barmar is prob. better solution, though I avoided awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat filename | grep "^second" | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Or, if you are ALF:

```
<filename grep "^second" | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Or

```
grep "^second" filename | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Comment: i have not file , i have lines

Comment: Where are the lines if they're not in a file? If they're in a variable, use `echo "$variable"` instead of `cat filename`.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat` award!](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: What's wrong with the cat?  What would be better?  And why is OP talking like Master-Blaster from Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome?

Comment: Better is `grep "^second" filename`. And OP is probably not a native English speaker.

Comment: I kinda like the filename toward the beginning and flowing through a filter, but that's obviously personal opinion.  I don't think the overhead of cat is onerous. [Well, time check shows 0.001 slower for cat, even for a small file...]

Answer (score 1):

since you seem to not have any criterion as to which line you want to output, i suggest something like:

```
echo "ssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
```

this is pretty robust regarding the content of your input, doesn't depend on a "file", and is a fast solution.

Comment: Or a bit shorter: `printf "s%.0s" {1..25}`

Comment: @user000001, @Birei: i shouldn't have said "fastest solution"; i meant that is was faster than all the `grep` and `awk` solutions presented so far...

Comment: The may be some issues with robustness with this solution.